# How to set constraints when placing a collectionview inside tableview

Tags: swift, xcode

I am fairly new to Swift and need some guidance on setting up constraints. I have 6 labels stacked vertically in a cell. Towards the bottom of the cell I have a collection view that scrolls horizontally. And underneath this I have a row of buttons stacked horizontally.

Needless to say, it is a mess. I am just looking for some ideas on how to setup constraints and how to nest the stack views.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Edit:
Attached is a screenshot from the android equivalent. The light green boxes scroll horizontally fyi.

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words my friend. Currently, this is very opinion based and may get flagged if you don't add more details. This is to help others help you :)

Comment: Point taken. I've uploaded a screenshot